# Difference between "lay" and "bury"

Tags: meaning, difference

> Lay
>
> 3 [+ object] : **bury**
>
> They laid him in his grave (Merriam Webster Learner's Dictionary)
>
> ---
>
> Lay:
>
> to **bury**
>
> They laid him in the old churchyard. (Dictionary.com)

Take this sentence as an example.

They **laid/buried him** in the old churchyard.

What is the difference between "lay" and "bury"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is an issue with the definitions for each of the words you've provided.

To bury a person, you would first have to lay them in the hole **and then cover them in soil.**

It's worth noting though, that you don't always need to lay something in a hole to bury it. You can just pile *stuff* on top of anything to bury it.

> **Lay** - to put something in especially a flat or horizontal position, usually carefully or for a particular purpose [Cambridge Dictionary Def.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lay)
>
> **Bury** - to cover something or someone completely with a large quantity of something [Cambridge Dictionary Def.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bury?q=Bury)

---

Using your examples:

> They laid him in the old churchyard.

They put him [down] in the old churchyard. (Note that this isn't necessarily in a grave)

> They buried him in the old churchyard.

They covered him in something in the churchyard. (Note that you would always assume that if you bury someone in a churchyard, you always mean that you have buried them in a grave with soil.)

Comment: *They laid his ghost to rest* also doesn't mean that they *buried* his ghost. The two words *can* imply the same thing, but *lay* has several other senses that *bury* does not.

Comment: Yes, I have just covered the meanings which are relevant to the OP. There are plenty of other definitions for the lay which are covered in the links provided.

Comment: "They laid him in the old churchyard" may not _necessarily_ mean burial in a grave, but, in most contexts, that's exactly what it will mean. See Def. 2b at [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lay): **lay** (*v.*)  to place for rest or sleep; especially : `BURY`.